# Does HAProxy support logging to a file?

Tags: logs, haproxy

I've just installed **haproxy** on my test server.

Is there a way of making it write its logs to a local file, rather than syslog?

This is only for testing so I don't want to start opening ports / cluttering up syslog with all my test data.

Unfortunately, the only information I can find all revolves around logging to a syslog server.

I tried using:

```
log /home/user/ha.log local0
```

in my config. But that told me:

```
[ALERT] 039/095022 (9528) : sendto logger #1 failed: No such file or directory (errno=2)
```

When I restarted. So I created the file with `touch /home/user/ha.log` and restarted at which point I got:

```
[ALERT] 039/095055 (9593) : sendto logger #1 failed: Connection refused (errno=111)
```

Is this possible, or am I going to have to configure syslog etc. to see my test data?

Comment: I don't think HAProxy can log to a file, and I suspect the reason for this is that writes to disk are a blocking operation.  Why do you *really* not want to use syslog? Config is not all that tricky. You can assign a local facility to HAProxy and configure your syslog daemon to write those entries to a different file, and not to other syslog files (or network streams), if you're not wanting the HAProxy logs not to be mixed in with everything else.

Answer (score 21):

Haproxy simply doesn't support logging to files.
As stated in the documentation (https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.8/configuration.html#3.1-log), the "log" statement takes as first parameter an address.
If that's a file, it's a unix socket and HAProxy will speak in the syslog format to this socket.
Haproxy is designed like this because its responsability is to proxy requests, not write files, it delegates writing of log files to syslog.
If you don't want to mess with your machine, you can for example install logstash and run:

`logstash -e 'input { unix { path => "/tmp/haprxoy_log.sock"  } } output { stdout { } }'`

and add:

`log /tmp/haprxoy_log.sock`

In your haproxy.cfg to test it.

Comment: I'm getting "E: Unable to locate package logstash". Was logstash removed from ubuntu?

Comment: @user568021 seems logstash is not provided in ubuntu, but elastic (logstash's maintainer) provides an apt source. Also, logstash is a java software, so you might be able to run it by downloading a jar file running it with a JRE (which is provided by ubuntu)

Answer (score 11):

You can change haproxy log config file under `/etc/rsyslog.d/` to point the file to the path you like. Not sure about other distribution. For me, I'm using Debian. I changed `/etc/rsyslog.d/49-haproxy.conf` to point to `/var/log/haproxy/haproxy.log`,

```
# Create an additional socket in haproxy's chroot in order to allow logging via
# /dev/log to chroot'ed HAProxy processes
$AddUnixListenSocket /var/lib/haproxy/dev/log

# Send HAProxy messages to a dedicated logfile
:programname,startswith,"haproxy" /var/log/haproxy/haproxy.log
```

You should also update the log path in `/etc/logrotate.d/haproxy` to the new path. So that it will rotate and compress logfile in newly configured path using `gzip`.

Then restart rsyslog.service.

```
sudo systemctl restart rsyslog.service
```

Now `haproxy.log.*` file will be in `/var/log/haproxy/` directory.

Comment: How do I create separate log for errors like /var/log/haproxy-errors.log without affecting the original haproxy.log?

Answer (score 7):

**Since version [1.9 HAProxy supports](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/haproxy-1-9-has-arrived/) logging to `stdout` and `stderr`.**

With that in mind it's pretty trivial to pipe it to a file.

```
# change haproxy.cfg file with the following
global
    log stdout local0 debug

defaults
    log global
    option httplog
```

And then you can simply run HAProxy like this:

```
haproxy -f haproxy.cfg > haproxy.log 2>&1 &
```

As you probably know `>` pipes `stdout` to the file `haproxy.log` and then `2>&1` pipes `stderr` also to the same file. It ends with `&` that will put the process in the background.

You can get fancier and try to setup a script to kill the previous instance of `haproxy` by doing something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# mini launcher
kill -9 `cat /home/user/haproxy.pid`
/home/user/haproxy -f /home/haproxy.cfg > /home/user/haproxy.log 2>&1 &
echo $! > /home/user/haproxy.pid
```

<del>Tough, as you can probably tell... **not recommended.**</del>

Edit: Logging to files used to be a blocking event and thus, not recommended, specially for something like HAProxy. The HAProxy team made it abundantly clear on the release post linked above that this is **not the case anymore**.

> We’ve received this request quite a bit and have spent some time
> planning the best way to implement it—without blocking—and we’re
> pleased to announce that we’ve found a solution!

Comment: why is logging to stdout/err "not recommended"? is this your opinion or is there official documentation about problems with that?

Comment: @Florian, you are correct. I was misguided by past behaviour. It does not block on recent releases thus the sentence was opinionative (and wrong). Edited the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Frankie getting error `sendmsg()/writev() failed in logger #1: Connection refused (errno=111)` with a file read/writable by haproxy. Doc says `A file descriptor number in the form "fd@<number>", which may point to a pipe, terminal, or socket.` How do we know fd before process starts? Doc says `Exceptionally for debugging purposes the file descriptor may also be directed to a file, but doing so will significantly slow HAProxy down as non-blocking calls will be ignored. Also there will be no way to purge nor rotate this file without restarting the process.` How to redirect that fd to file?

Comment: @SameerNaik what HAProxy version are you using? Since 1.9 this should be straightforward - just like the example above.

Comment: We are using version 2.0.7. We are trying to redirect output to a regular file by specifying its full path instead of `stdout`

Comment: @SameerNaik when you mean redirect output... you can just do this `haproxy -f haproxy.cfg > haproxy.log 2>&1 &` right? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, we can do that or do it via systemd `StandardOutput=file:/var/log/haproxy.log` but wanted to make sure if there is easier way of just specifying full path of log file in config itself.

Comment: @SameerNaik try `log /dev/log local2 debug`, should also work. I don't have access to a HAProxy installation right now, but will test later if it doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You have tried to configured in the user home directory, haproxy doesn't have permission to access user's home directory, so that cause issue.

Instead try in other location, create directory in `/var/<directory>`

```
log /var/<directory>/ha.log
```

Comment: I tried `sudo touch /var/log/ha.log` and added `log /var/log/ha.log local0` to my config, but got the same error as above `connection refused`.

Comment: In log why you giving local0 in the end?

Comment: I tried leaving it out, but when I restarted I got the error `'log' expects <address> and <facility> as arguments.` so required something there. According to the instructions `<facility> must be one of the 24 standard syslog facilities` (which I think may be part of the problem)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a log service in order for haproxy to be able to log to specific files. Use following instructions, which worked for me in EL7 and HAProxy 2.7-dev5:-

yum install rsyslog

vi /etc/rsyslog.d/haproxy.conf

```
$ModLoad imudp
$UDPServerAddress 127.0.0.1
$UDPServerRun 514

local2.*        /logdir/haproxy
local3.*        /logdir/haproxy-access_log
```

systemctl restart rsyslog && ldconfig

vi /../../haproxy.cfg

```
global
        log stderr local0 info
        log 127.0.0.1 local2 notice
        log 127.0.0.1 local3

defaults 
        log global
        option httplog
```

systemctl restart haproxy

Don't forget to setup log rotation service as well, to avoid unnecessary space consumption and following should do the job:-

vi /etc/logrotate.d/haproxy

```
/logdir/logdir/haproxy-access_log {
  weekly
  rotate 7
  missingok
  size=5M
  notifempty
  dateext
  dateformat -%d%m%Y
  compress
  create 0644 logfileowner logfileowner
  su logfileowner logfileowner
  mail email@torecievelogs
  postrotate
    /usr/bin/systemctl reload haproxy
  endscript
}
```

Also, run the following two commands to find out if there is any problem with log rotation:-

```
logrotate --force /etc/logrotate.d/haproxy
grep logrotate /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2why
```

Lastly, hereby I note if security-enhanced is enabled you might need to tweak log files context and its parent directory.

Good luck :).

Zakaria.